# Nested/hierarchically collapse and expand in Excel or other application

Tags: excel-2007

I want to hierarchically collapse/expand in Excel, or if not in Excel then in any other application. e.g. I have:

```
  ABC
   -abcd
   -abc1
   -abc2
      -a1
      -a2
        -MM2
        -NN2
      -a3
    -abc3
```

when what I want to see is:

```
+ABC _further if I expand ABC- I should get_
ABC
 -abcd
 -abc1
 +abc2 _likewise_.
```

I tried data Group and Ungroup in MS-EXCEL, but without success and have not found a satisfactory answer on the internet.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried again, though I’m still not certain this is what you would like. With **Data, Outline, Summary rows below total** unchecked, select the rows containing –MM2 and –NN2 and Group, select the rows containing -a1, -a2, -a3 and Group, select the rows containing –abcd, -abc1, -abc2 and -abc3 and Group.

[image: SO12612763 example]

The result should be as on the right above and the first, second and third levels shown from the left.